# Java: Using Regex to omit text

Tags: java, regex, hide

Hi I'm using Regex to omit text in java, conditionally.

```
String pattern= "(#<omit_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+>)(.+?)(<omit_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+>)";

Mary had a #<omit_size>little <omit_size>lamb, his fleece was white as snow.
```

My pattern works fine in the above example to find what needs to be hidden (or not).

My problem arises when I may need to hide something within something which may also need to be hidden. e.g.:

```
Mary had a #<omit_segment> #<omit_size>little <omit_size>lamb, his <omit_segment> fleece was white as snow.
```

The above pattern is limited in that it can not distinguish between the many character arrangements which may follow `'#<omit_'` . So if I only wish to hide that which resides between `'#<omit_segment>... <omit_segment>'` My pattern instead looks at  `'#<omit_segment> ...#<omit_size> '` and, as such will print :

```
Mary had a little <omit_size>lamb, his <omit_segment> fleece was white as snow.
```

instead of the desired:

```
Mary had a fleece was white as snow.
```

I realise that Regex may not be the answer for something like this, but before I undo a lot of stuff, I thought I'd see if anything can be salvaged. so.. any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I can make a regex that works for this case, but it will fail when you have nesting of the same tag. For arbitrary nesting, you should use a stack keep track of the opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String pattern= "(#(<omit_[\\w_]+>))(.*[^#])(\\2)";
String pattern= "(#(<omit_[\\w_]+>))(.+)(?<!#)(\\2)";
```

The `\\2` matches the second group, the precise tag `<...>`.
So if the tag names differ on nesting this may function.

Both version check that the ending part is not preceded by `#`.
In the second case with a negative lookbehind (0 length in matching).

Comment: Great stuff lads (Joop and Ravi). Regular Expressions never cease to amaze me.

Comment: @HellishHeat Yeah, no need to give up on them! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck. Use a back reference to match on the correct ending omit keyword.

```
(#<omit_(\\w+)>)(.+)(?<!#)(<omit_\\2>)
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please at least try the regex first. It was tested before I posted here. If it doesn't meet your requirements you can let me know and I'll write you a new one.